# How to get angles of a triangle given three slopes from each line

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I need a formula to tell whether a trigonometry corner has an obtuse angle or not, given slopes value of each line connecting every two points respectively. Assuming I have three points

```
| X(1,3). . . . .
| . . . . Y(5,2).
| . . Z(3,1). . .
|________________
```

So, their slopes will be

```
XY : -1/4
XZ : -1
YZ : 1/2
```

So from given slopes as variables, we'll be able to tell that point Z has an obtuse angle. The rest are acute of course. But I can't figure out how to do it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: disclaimer : this is not an assignment question. i just need to find a programming solution

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I have updated my Answer , making it much simple to use in your case.

Answer (score 4):

Take Origin = Point $Z$ , which means , we have to subtract the Co-ordinates from the other Points , to get :

$Z=(0,0)$
$X=(1-3,3-1)$
$Y=(5-3,2-1)$

We have to now get the Angle between the "vectors" $ZY$ & $ZX$

---

Standard Way is to calculate this with $\cos^{-1}([{X}\cdot{Y}]/[|X||Y|])$

Let the new "vectors" be $X=(x1,x2)$ & $Y=(y1,y2)$
Then the Angle between these two is $\cos^{-1}([x1y1+x2y2]/[\sqrt{x1^2+y1^2}\sqrt{x2^2+y2^2}])$

In this Method, we actually do not have to compute the $\cos^{-1}(\cdot)$ , we can simply check the SIGN of the argument : when it is Negative , we conclude that it is Obtuse & when it is Positive , we conclude that it is Acute.

More-over, we can avoid Squaring & Division because that will not change the SIGN.

**We only have to calculate $[x1y1+x2y2]$ & Check the SIGN !**

This Method is Very Efficient , requiring only Subtraction , Multiplication & Addition.

Check more on this with keywords : Dot Product & Normalization of vectors.

---

In given Example:
We get $\cos^{-1}([(-2)(+2)+(2)(1)]/[\sqrt{(-2)^2+(+2)^2}\sqrt{(+2)^2+(+1)^2}])$

$\cos^{-1}([-2]/[\sqrt{8}\sqrt{5}])$ , with Negative Argument , hence it has to be Obtuse Angle

$\cos^{-1}([-1]/[\sqrt{10}])=108$ (In Degrees)

Which is Indeed Obtuse Angle

Comment: thank you. let me try it

Answer (score 1):

Just note that the slope of a line in the coordinate plane equals $\tan{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between the line and the positive direction of the $x$-axis. So if we suppose that $\tan\alpha$, $\tan\beta$, and $\tan\gamma$ are given, then we can compute $\mid\tan(\alpha - \gamma)\mid$, $\mid\tan(\beta - \alpha)\mid$, and $\mid\tan(\gamma - \beta)\mid$ to find the absolute values of the tangent of the angles of our triangle. Note that $\tan(x - y) = \frac{\tan x - \tan y}{1 + \tan x.\tan y}$. So

If the given slopes are $m_1$, $m_2$, and  $m_3$, let $f(x, y) = \frac{x - y}{1 + xy}$ and then compute
\begin{align*}
f(m_1, m_3), f(m_2, m_1) \text{ and } f(m_3, m_2).
\end{align*}
If the sign of one of them is different, then the triangle has an obtuse angle.

Comment: Amazing, when we had to prove this tangens theorem as homework in the first semester I had no imagination for what case this theorem ever would be useful.
However, how do you make sure that $tan(x - y) < 0 \Rightarrow |x - y| > 90^o$? When it is negative, it could also just mean, y is slightly larger than x? `f` is anti-commutative in the sense that swapping argument order negates the value. The slope of XY is equal to the slope of YX. With only two slopes, I think, it's impossible to figure out the corner angle. The third one is required.

Comment: @ChrisoLosoph You can check that for a triangle with side slopes $\tan\alpha$, $\tan\beta$, and $\tan\gamma$, the absolute values of the tangent of the angles always equal $(|\tan(\alpha - \gamma)|, |\tan(\beta - \alpha)|, |\tan(\gamma - \beta)|)$. Now consider an arbitrary permutation of $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$, like $(\beta, \alpha, \gamma)$ or $(\gamma, \alpha, \beta)$, then the order of $(\alpha - \gamma, \beta - \alpha, \gamma - \beta)$ will change to $(\beta - \gamma, \alpha - \beta, \gamma - \alpha)$ or $(\gamma - \beta, \alpha - \gamma, \beta - \alpha)$, respectively.

Comment: You can see that after changing the order of $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$, the terms of the set $\{\alpha - \gamma, \beta - \alpha, \gamma - \beta\}$ remain the same, or the sign of all changed simultaneously. So no matter how you choose the order of the angles, after computing three values $(\tan(\alpha - \gamma), \tan(\beta - \alpha), \tan(\gamma - \beta))$, you can say the triangle has a obtuse angle or not. If all are positive or negative, the answer is NO, otherwise, the answer is YES. As you said, in this method, you always need to compute all of these three values.

Answer (score 1):

When co ordinates of $A,B,C$ or lengths $AB,BC,AC$ are given the the cosine rule is the best, keeping in mind that angle opposite the largest side the largest.
But if three slopes ($m_1,m_2,m_3$ in any order) or equations of lines are given then one can use the following method. Find $$t_3 = \left|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right|$$ similarly $t_1,t_2.$ then check if
$$t_1+t_2+t_3=t_1 t_2 t_3......(1)$$ is satisfied then
three positive acute angles  are $T_i=\tan^{-1} t_i$

If not  then  replace the the highest of them  (let $t_2$) by $-t_2$ in  both sides of (1). Then
$$t_1-t_2+t_3=-t_1t_2t_3........(2)$$
will get satisfied meaning that the triangle is obtuse and its positive angles are: $T_1, \pi-\tan^{-1}t_2, T_3$, with $\pi-\tan^{-1}t_2$ being the obtuse angle.

EDIT:

In OP's question $m_1=-1/4, m_2=1/2,m_3=-1$ giving $t_1=3, t_2=3/5, t_3=6/7$. Check that
$3+3/5+6/7 \ne \frac{54}{35}$ so it is not an acute angle triangle. Next. check  that $-3+3/5+6/7= -\frac{54}{35}$ implyimg that it is an obtuse triangle and the obtuse angle is $(\pi-\tan^{-1} 3)$ which is nothing but $\cos^{-1} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{10}}=1.8925...rads=108.435...deg$
as obtained by @Prem below by cosine rule

Comment: Cool! What is the name of this theorem (1) ? I found myself a proof using $-\tan (\beta + \gamma) = \frac{\tan \beta + \tan \gamma}{\tan \beta \tan \gamma - 1}$ and figured out that (1) holds when $0 \equiv \alpha + \beta + \gamma  \mod \pi$ with the greek letters as corner angles. If the triangle is acute, then all tangents are positive by themselves. If the triangle is obtuse, then the largest angle has a negative tangent. It has the greatest absolute value since $|\tan -\alpha| = |\tan \alpha|$ and $|\tan \beta|,|\tan \gamma| < |\tan (\pi - \alpha)| = |\tan \alpha|$ using monotonicity.

Comment: But it seems, as if this formular will also find rectangular non-acute triangles. Formula (1) is satisfied for all triangles wth rectangular angle (at least for standard IEEE754 floating point computations). For colinear points, the formula will compare equality of NaN with NaN which returns false. This corner case works.

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to comparing degree or radiant values.

Let us imagine the triangle to be an intersection of three infinite lines. When we move the lines into into a common point, so that they only intersect in one single point, we can easily compare each slope with a 90° rotated slope since slope values are monotonous like values in radiant and degree. When we compare adjacent slope values, i.e. maximum value with middle value and middle value with minimum value, the positive difference represents the angle between them in the triangle (without considering the distortion factor here). Only when comparing the maximum and the minimum slope value the reversed difference needs to be used to represent the angle in the triangle.

But since the problem is not about computing angles, we only need to compare the middle and the minimum slope value against a sensible threshold value.

Let $s_{max} > s_{mid} > s_{min}$ be the three slope values. Then, this holds if and only if it is an acute triangle:

(F1)
$$s_{max} > s_{mid} > s_{max,90°} > s_{min}$$
$$s_{mid,90°} \not\in [ s_{min} , s_{max} ]$$

where $s_{max,90°} = -1/s_{max}$ and $s_{mid,90°} = -1/s_{mid}$.

Obviously, there is a right angle, if either $s_{mid} = s_{max,90°}$ or $s_{min} = s_{max,90°}$ or $s_{min} = s_{mid,90°}$.

In consequence, you cannot have an accute triangle if $s_{max} \le 0$ or if $s_{min} \ge 0$. $s_{max,90°}$ must be between $s_{mid}$ and $s_{min}$, $s_{mid,90°}$ must be the biggest or smallest value.

Also note, that it does not matter for the angles how you move the lines around as long as they are not rotated individually.
**All triangles produced by arbitrarily moving these lines around have an equal set of enclosed angles.**

Why?
If you have 3 parallel equidistant lines, you get 2 concruent infinitely long stripe areas in between them. If you add another 3 parallel equidistant lines into a different direction, you get 4 parallelograms in between these 6 lines. Now if you add another 3 parallel equidistant lines but exactly in the way so that they cut the parallelograms into triangles, you have 8 concruent triangles of which the inner 6 triangles are the triangles that you can get from moving around the lines (classes of triangles which are isomorphic except for the length units).

This justifies that the lines can be moved into one point as an explanation to read out the angles. It also explains visually why the sum of internal angles sum up to 180°.

### Linear Algebra approach

Consider each slope to be a 2D vector. Only the $x$ value is interesting which is the slope value, the $y$ value is always 1. **We can "pre-process" the vector space, mapping it into a standard basis so that $s_{max}' = \infty$ and $s_{max,90°} = 0$.** This allows for quick comparisons replacing some few comparisons with arithmetic instructions. If any slope value is not finite, then the standard-basis is already established and pre-processing must be skipped. Also note that $-\infty$ should be treated as $\infty$ in this case.

Since we don't care for lengths, our pre-processing transformation doesn't need to be an orthogonal matrix, its a scaled rotation.

This rotation matrix only needs to compute the $x$ value of the result because the $y$ does carry quantitative but not *qualitative* information about the angle.

The required transformation is the inverse matrix of
$$\mathbf{M} = \left[\array{s_{max,1} & s_{max,90°,1} \\ s_{max,2} & s_{max, 90°, 2}}\right] = \left[\array{s_{max} & -1 \\ 1 & s_{max}}\right]$$

For the computation of the inverse, the determinant can be ignored because it's just a scaling factor. The inverse therefore is $f_{\mathbf{M}^{-1}}(s) = s_{max} \cdot s + 1$ or $f_{\mathbf{M}^{-1}}(s) = s$ if the preprocessing is skipped.

The pre-processing transformation maps the $s_{max}$ vector to x-axis and it's 90° rotated vector to the y-axis.

Then the triangle has solely acute angles if and only if

(F2)
$$f_{\mathbf{M}^{-1}}(s_{mid}) > 0 > f_{\mathbf{M}^{-1}}(s_{min})$$
$$s_{mid,90°} \not\in [ s_{min} , s_{max} ]$$

where $s_{mid,90°} = -1/s_{mid}$.

We only need to compare against 0 because in the standard basis, x = 0 represents the 90° rotate maximum slope value. The formula cannot be satisfied when $\mathbf{M}$ rotates vectors by $\ge 90°$. After the transformation, the $y$ value monotonously decreases for increasing slope values so that the monotonicity of the actual slope values $x/y$ still is preserved. A rotation below 90° will not change the qualitative order of vectors (previously sorted by $x$-axis when each had the same $y$ value) and therefore F2 should be satisfied if and only if F1 is satisfied.